# MySQL distinct on one column with other max column

Tags: mysql, distinct

Let's say I have this query:

```
SELECT report_id, time_sent
FROM  report_submissions
WHERE report_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
ORDER BY report_id ASC, time_sent DESC
```

with this result:

```
report_id   time_sent
1           2
1           1
2           4
2           3
3           4
```

And I want to change that query so I will get a DISTINCT report_id with its max(time_sent), for example:

```
report_id   time_sent
1           2
2           4
3           4
```

How do I do that in the most efficient way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT report_id, max(time_sent)
FROM  report_submissions
WHERE report_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY report_id
ORDER BY report_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is a lazy `GROUP BY`!

```
SELECT report_id, max(time_sent)
FROM  report_submissions
WHERE report_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY report_id
ORDER BY report_id ASC, max(time_sent) DESC
```

Comment: Because ironically, **I** was lazy and copy-pasted the original, then made it valid.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `group by`

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html